# Text Input GUI CLI for Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gui

I'd like to set up the following workflow on my (Gnome) Ubuntu 21.10 laptop.

- Enter a shortcut to run a program (let's say a bash script)
- A GUI text-input (preferably GTK) pops up and offers a text input
- I type in some task
- I call an API and send task information to my todolist via a REST api

I know how to implement each part, except which CLI to use to prompt for text from a GUI (rather than a CLI).

**Question**

- Which CLI can I use to perform to prompt for user input via a GUI textbox?

Comment: I think you're confusing your terminologies quite a bit. There's no real distinction between CLI and GUI programs. A "CLI" application that opens a GUI and doesn't interact with the user on the command line at all isn't a CLI. The manner in which a program was started, whether through the GUI application selector or through the shell bears no bearing on making an application CLI or GUI.

Comment: Apologies, the terminology was a little tricky. I was looking for a GUI with a useful CLI interface (like zenity), rather than a CLI that reads from a tty. But fair point, I'll keep this language clearer in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/index.html.en) is probably the easiest way to create simple GUI dialogs from shell scripts. The [input dialog](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/entry.html.en) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TASK=`zenity --entry --text="Enter task:"`

echo $TASK
```

[image]